# Is $\arg$ ever used on its own?

Tags: notation, index-notation

I am familiar with the use of $\arg$ in $\arg \min$ or $\arg \max$.

Would you ever use $\arg$ to define a set of arguments where a condition is true?

Can I use these two notations interchangeably or is the second line not a canonical use of $\arg$?

$X = \{i : z_i = 1\}$

$X = \arg_i z_i = 1$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the use of $\arg \max$ etc. in optimization and discrete maths. The coverage on wikipedia is reasonable [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max), where a standard expression is
$$
\arg \max_{x \in S}f(x) :=\{x \in S: f(y)\leq f(x)~for~all~y\in S\}.
$$

However the notation you propose is totally unclear, I doubt it's used anywhere, you must have come up with it. Stick to
$$
X=\{i:x_i=1\},
$$
instead.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I did come up with it. It just made so much sense to me, that I figured maybe I'm not the only one and it might also be used by others :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote
$$
X = \arg_i z_i = 1
$$
I would not know what you mean.

What branch of math uses notations $\arg$ and $\arg \min$ and $\arg \max$ ?

Comment: $\arg min$ is something that cropped up for me all over the place, from analysis to discrete math. An example would be optimization, where you want to find the parameters that optimize an expression. E.g. $\hat x = \arg \min_x f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is the function you want to minimize and $\hat x$ is the parameter that minimizes it.